# The text in the middle of post box

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

How I can put text in the middle of post box. I posting this post by Graph API

```
facebook_access_token.post("/me/feed", {
  :message => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
  :name => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
  :link => 'http://heiaheia.com',
  :description => ' ',
  :picture => 'http://images.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/justforfun/images/earth_20090309105503.jpg'
})
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "in the middle"?

Comment: I mean align the text 'Lorem ipsum ...' on the middle of image.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean vertically align it in the middle, then its not possible. Its box has a minimum height as you see.